# Partition Table Error

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Task - create partition for table by country iso
Write a query like this:

```
ALTER TABLE remake_town_city_full PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS (`country_iso`) 
(
PARTITION p_AD VALUES IN ('AD'),
PARTITION p_AE VALUES IN ('AE'),
PARTITION p_AF VALUES IN ('AF'),
PARTITION p_AG VALUES IN ('AG'),
...
PARTITION p_ZM VALUES IN ('ZM'),
PARTITION p_ZW VALUES IN ('ZW')
)
```

But mysql print error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMNS (`country_iso`)

I`m trying without COLUMNS but this not help for me
Where error? Thanks!

Comment: I find problem. In My Mysql version (5.1.73) i can`t use text for values: Partitioning in MySQL 5.1 can only deal with integer columns

Comment: Anyway, you will probably find no performance benefit.